# Get all planner tasks created by an user

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I want to get all tasks my user created.

I tried to use `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drive/root/createdByUser/planner/tasks` endpoint in the Graph Explorer, but I got error 500 (internal server error).

The official documentation is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/planneruser-list-tasks?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Do you have any suggestion how I can get all the planner tasks I created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tasks created by a user is not a supported query. People can lose access to tasks that they have created (e.g. if they are removed from groups). The closest operation you can do is to loop over the plans in the groups you are a member of, read the plans in those tasks and see which ones were created by your user. The API linked in the question will return the tasks assigned to you.